# Почему MySQL находит дубликаты даже после удаления дубликатов?

Tags: mysql

Это запрос на удаление дубликатов

```
DELETE t1 
FROM table t1 
LEFT JOIN table t2 
ON t1.token = t2.token AND t1.updated_at < t2.updated_at 
WHERE t2.token IS NOT NULL;
```

Это запрос на проверку наличия дубликатов

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
GROUP BY token 
HAVING count(token)>1
```

До удаления было более 12000 дубликатов, после - запрос показывает 44.
Вопрос: почему они остались, какой из этих запросов неправильный?
Или все дело в индексе по полю token?

Comment: дак выведите которые остались да посмотрите, что с ними не так. может у них `updated_at` равны?

Comment: Посмотрел. Среди тех 44 не вижу реальных дубликатов. Может быть, это особенность GROUP BY - не строгое сравнение, а по хэшу какому-нибудь и на больших данных появляются ошибки...

Comment: а вы нормальный запрос напишите сначала. `select * from t1 where token in (select token .... having count(token) > 1) order by token`. и если останутся вопросы, то результат сюда

Comment: `FROM ... LEFT JOIN table t2 ON ... WHERE t2.token IS NOT NULL` - ну бред же! Просто INNER JOIN, без WHERE.

Comment: @teran , вы были правы, это именно из-за равенства updated_at. вопрос только один остался, как лучше заставить этот запрос выбрать один вариант, не потеряв в производительности? (Наверно, лучший вариант уже после запроса DELETE поставить UNIQUE INDEX с удалением дубликатов, раз уж оставшиеся запросы равнозначны по приоритету)

Comment: @teran, оформите, пожалуйста, ваши советы и предположения в виде ответа. я отмечу как решение, вы реально помогли мне.

Comment: а вы пронумеруйте строки в группах по токенам, и удалите все что больше 1.